# Viewport argument value "device-width;" error in iOS inspector

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I've been having an issue with my mobile app redirecting to a blank white screen when I try to use Azure's mobile service OAuth. It only occurs when running on the actual device.

It's an Ionic/Cordova app and I'm trying to authenticate through Azure's mobile services. I get this error when I inspect the app running on my phone through safari's page inspector:

Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated.

Here's the code, I think that the semi-colons should be comma's, but I'm not really sure how to fix that because this is the authentication page generated when I make the call to the mobile service.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you install the plugin?  The current source is using commas (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Javascript/src/LoginUis/CordovaPopup.js#L133)

Comment: Honestly I forget how I originally installed. I looked and when following one of the tutorials I updated my MobileServices script reference to point to a CDN. I'll have to update the library and get back to you. Thanks!